# Grepping Ruby hash for regex not working as expected

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I have a hash with this data:

```
{"ENABLED"=>
[#<Details:0x00007f910e946848
@context="ELP",
@instance="a1",
@side="blue",
@status="ENABLED",
@vm="ome-vm58",
@vmaddr="ajp://10.133.248.4:8009">,

... snip ...

#<Details:0x00007f910e944070
@context="learnItLive",
@instance="b2",
@side="green",
@status="ENABLED",
@vm="ome-vm61",
@vmaddr="ajp://10.133.248.7:8159">]}
```

The hash is called `status_hash`. I want to determine if the key is ENABLED or not. The other potential key values are DISABLED, STOPPED, and WAITING.

These lines:

```
puts "Status key: " + status_hash.keys.to_s
puts "1 - Cluster has Disabled, Stopped, or Waiting contexts" if status_hash.keys.grep(/^[DSW]/)
```

Produces output, even though the key is "ENABLED"

```
Status key: ["ENABLED"]
1 - Cluster has Disabled, Stopped, or Waiting contexts
```

I don't understand why the regex is matching when the first character in the key is an `E` and not in `DSW`.

Comment: You say, "I want to determine if *the key* is ENABLED or not" (emphasis mine). That suggests to me that the hash has just one key. In that's the case, do you not want simply `status_hash.keys.first == 'ENABLED'`?

Comment: The example I provided has but one key. There are four possible key values, and in an error situation, more than one will be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `.any?` on `grep` results

```
puts "1 - Cluster has Disabled, Stopped, or Waiting contexts" if status_hash.keys.grep(/^[DSW]/).any?
```

---

The reason, why the issue was occurring, was `grep` returned empty array `[]` which is considered truthy. So we need to apply `any?`, which returns true if there is any element in an array.

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable#grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) always returns an array and even though your results produces `[]` that is truthy in ruby.

Example:

```
p 'hello world' if [].grep(/hi/).empty?
"hello world"
=> "hello world"
p 'hello world' if ![].grep(/hi/).empty?
=> nil
```